# What's the best way to add title to a menu screen in pygame

Tags: pygame

So, for a school assignment, I need to make a game on Adult Education and so I did but just for the basics, I cannot figure out how to add a title on my menu screen in this game. I have tried many other tutorials and some are pretty easy to understand but for some reason, it ends up not working in my program. What is the best way to add a simple title in pygame?

Heres the code(If you would like to check for any errors I have made):

```
# Program: Import Library, Pygame, for initialization of this program
import pygame
# Initialize the game engine
pygame.init()

# Define Colours

BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN    = (   0, 255,   0)
RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)
BLUE     = (   0,   0, 255)

size = (1080, 720)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("MiniConomy Trivia, for Adults")

#Loop until the user clicks the close button
done = False

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
 
    # Set the screen background
    screen.fill(BLUE)
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Setting a Title Screen
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 100)

    # Creating a Title Screen
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("MiniConomy", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have here is mostly syntactically correct (except for a couple of variable names which don't exist) but it isn't in the right order.

the "Creating a title screen" section should be out of the loop, the first two lines:

```
TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("MiniConomy", largeText)
TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
```

should be placed before the game loop and then the blit function:

```
gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
```

should be at the end of the game loop but instead of "gameDisplay" write "screen" instead as that is what you called your display at the start of the program.
The function "text_objects" should also go at the start of the program otherwise it cannot be called.

Here's the full modified code: https://pastebin.com/hQDbD2ya
Which produces this title screen:[image]

Comment: Also, how will be able to adjust the text position? like you showed me, the position is in the centre but how I will be able to move it to the top?

Comment: Change TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2)) to the coordinates you want the text to display at e.g. TextRect.center = (300,250)